# How to intercept a single method using SpringBoot AOP

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm trying to output a log message whenever the function someFunction() gets invoked.

This is my Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyAspect.class.getName());

    @Pointcut("execution(com.practice.AOP.someFunction())")
    public void outputLogMessage() {
        LOGGER.info("someFunction has been invoked");
    }
}
```

The method i'm trying to intercept, someFunction(), is in the com.practice.AOP class. When I invoke it (shown below), my Advice (the log message) doesn't output, nor do I get an error. What am I doing wrong? Is Pointcut even the way to go?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AOP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        someFunction();
    }

    public static void someFunction() {
        //should invoke the log message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOP only works on Spring beans, and only on public instance methods of those spring beans invoked from the outside (i.e. `this.publicMethod()` style invocations will not work, as they are not going through the proxies that Spring AOP creates to advise your spring beans.

If that is not enough for you, for instance if you need to advise not just spring beans but non-spring managed code as well, or static methods like in your example, you will need to switch to native AspectJ support, either by compile time weaving, or by load time weaving.